# Difference between Sensitivity analysis and Design of Experiments

Tags: experiment-design, sensitivity-analysis

Reading on wikipedia about [the methods for sensitivity analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis#Core_methodology): different methods are stated.

At the end of the wikipedia page, a section called [Related Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis#Related_concepts) speaks about Design of experiments (DOE) as a related subject to sensitivity analysis.

Before I supposed that DOE is a method for doing a sensitivity analysis, but now I get lost. Even though they stated in the wikipedia page that both sensitivity analysis and DOE are used to detect the effect and influence of the parameters of a model.

Can someone help me to know the difference between these two concepts?

Answer (score 2):

Design of experiment (DOE) is composed of a set of methods which determine how to best choose points in a space.

You can want to choose these points for sensitivity analysis purposes but also for many other purposes such as supervised regression, classification.

For example, factorial designs are well suited for linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

sensitivity analysis explore the effect of small variation of the controlled variables around a set point/ polarization point, while DOE is exploring the full domain